# How to run a task in background of the app without leting user that is running?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to run a task in the background of the app without letting the user that is running? if a user navigates to a different screen then also that task works until it's done how can I do this in rn expo app?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Button } from 'react-native';
import NavbarBottom from '../NavbarBottom';

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {

const onPressLearnMore = () => { // How can i run this function in background? 

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log("Yes, Task Is Running In BackGround")
  navigation.navigate('learnmore')
}

}

  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar />
      <NavbarBottom navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />
        <Button
        onPress={onPressLearnMore}
        title="Learn More"
        color="#841584"
        />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a task in a parent component, like a navigator, and that will persist while the navigator is active.

If you need more complex task management, you could try redux-sagas; they're a robust way to perform logic outside of any components.